# User control properties (collection elements) don't get saved properly to the designer

Tags: vb.net, collections, user-controls, visual-studio-2015

I have a user control with a Collection property.

```
Public Class DbGrid
   <Browsable(True), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always),
         DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)>
    Public Property DbFields As DbFields
        Get
            If _DbFields Is Nothing Then
                _DbFields = New DbFields
            End If
            Return _DbFields
        End Get
        Set(value As DbFields)
            _DbFields = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

The collection is defined like this:

```
Public Class DbFields
    Inherits ObjectModel.Collection(Of DbField)

End Class

Public Class DbField
    Private _FieldId As String
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Field ID
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    Public Property FieldId As String
        Get
            Return _FieldId
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _FieldId = value
        End Set
    End Property
''... many more properties like this...''
End Class
```

The problem is that, after i add some items, the designer saves the code like this:

```
DbField1.FieldId = "field_id"
New MyProjectName.DbFields().Add(DbField1)
```

It should be like this:

```
DbField1.FieldId = "field_id"
DbGrid1.DbFields().Add(DbField1)
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: At a minimum you need to use the `DesignerSerializationVisibility` attribute to serialize the *contents* of the `DbFields` property.  You probably need to mark `DbField`as Serializable too.

Comment: Good articles on collections and designer serialization: [How to Edit and Persist Collections with CollectionEditor](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5372/How-to-Edit-and-Persist-Collections-with-Collectio) and [Enhanced CollectionEditor Framework](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/718006/Enhanced-CollectionEditor-Framework)

Comment: I didnt see it at first because of the scroll, but `.Visible` will not work because VS cannot serialize a collection object, just the `Contents`.  This will likely involve a TypeConverter for the item class (DbField).

Comment: Thank you @Plutonix, based on your comments and your second link helped a lot, I managed to resolve the problem. Changed `.Visible` to `.Content` and implemented a TypeConverter for `DbField` class.

Comment: Disclaimer (as if anyone cares) the second article is mine.